# When a boolean or int are placed in a java Map that contains Objects, does emplacing them actually create a new Object?

Tags: java, performance

Since in Java, generics usually operate on `Object` under the hood, I was curious if emplacing such values incurs more overhead than placing an already existing object.

Consider having a `Map<String, Object>` that can contain arbitrary meta-information. You want to put a flag kinda entry there - if it is present, the flag is enabled.

So you have something like this:

```
static final String MY_FLAG_NAME = "name";
Map<String, Object> myMap;
```

Now I wonder if there is a difference between these three implementations of setting the flat:

1. `myMap.put(MY_FLAG_NAME, true)` (`false` to disable)
2. `myMap.put(MY_FLAG_NAME, null)` (we can use `containsKey`, but this looks dirty to me)
3. `myMap.put(MY_FLAG_NAME, MY_FLAG_NAME)` (string is already allocated, and we can use `""` for disable)

My question here is if this will force at some point some kind of `new Boolean()` under the hood, or if it does not matter whether I put a string or a boolean. I never really got to understand how precisely Java handles the `boolean`/`Boolean` difference in generics, the same for other primitive types.

This code would be called a lot, but I don't have enough Java knowledge to make a trustworthy performance test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boxing constant `boolean`s (like the literals `true` and `false`) does not create arbitrarily many new objects. The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) says:

> If the value p being boxed is the result of evaluating a constant expression (§15.29) of type `boolean`, [...], and the result is `true`, `false`, [...], then let `a` and `b` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `a == b`.

If it is not a constant boolean expression (e.g. `someString.length() == 5`), the language specification doesn't guarantee boxing to produce the same object, but I think any reasonable implementation would implement boolean boxing as calling [`Boolean.valueof(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(boolean)), which does not create arbitrarily many new `Boolean` objects. It just returns the static final fields `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`. Of course, new `Boolean` objects will be created when the `TRUE` and `FALSE` fields are initialised, but no other `Boolean` objects will be created if you only use `Boolean.valueOf`.

> Returns a `Boolean` instance representing the specified boolean value. If the specified boolean value is `true`, this method returns `Boolean.TRUE`; if it is `false`, this method returns `Boolean.FALSE`.

Comment: So basically passing a final string and passing a boolean literal is the exact same thing, it reuses the object created behind the scenes already, if I understand this right?

Comment: @TomášZato Yes, in the sense that no unnecessary objects are created.

Comment: @OP You'd be interested to know that all primitives are boxed in this sense (usually akin to a `BoxedPrimitive#valueOf(primitive)`), but some have a limited range that they cache (e.g. `int`/`Integer` used to cache the byte range, not sure if that was extended).

Comment: Addendum: the public constructors of the class `Boolean` have been marked as “*Deprecated, for removal*” which means that even the hypothetical implementations currently not boxing non-constant expressions via `valueOf` will have to adopt it. Or, in other words, in a not-so-far future, it will be guaranteed that there are only the two `Boolean` instances.